# Error: only one usage of each socket address is normally permitted mosquitto

Tags: mosquitto

I have configured the mosquitto broker to listen to port 8883 which is the port that will be used for making ssl connections from the mosquitto broker. I restarted mosquitto broker using the following command

```
mosquitto -v -c mosquitto.conf
```

I encountered an error:
Only one usage of each socket address is permitted. What is this error and how to solve this error?

Comment: Can you please post the contents of mosquitto.conf

Answer (score 1):

The command you have typed is not the command to restart mosquitto.
You can type `sudo service mosquitto restart` to restart the mosquitto service which by default loads `/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf` if you're running linux.

The error you have seen has occured because mosquitto service may be already running on port 1883 and you have tried to run mosquitto again on that port.

Better to stop the service or restart it.
To stop mosquitto - `sudo service mosquitto stop`
Status - `sudo service mosquitto status`

Comment: I have seen this problem even when my Microsoft Windows 7's Task Manager shows that the Mosquitto broker is not running.  I had started and stopped mosquitto.exe several times before this problem occurred.   I suspect that something was left behind the last time that I stopped mosquitto.exe that made it appears that the socket was still in use.  Rebooting worked around the problem.